# If μ is a measure on [0,1] and ∫xndμ(x)=0 for all n≥0, show that μ=0

Tags: real-analysis

If $\mu$ is a measure on $[0,1]$ and $\int x^n d\mu(x)=0  $ for all $n\geq0$, show that $\mu=0$.

For this I know that there is an increasing sequence $\{s_k\}$ of step functions such that $s_k\to x^n$. Also $0=\int x^n d\mu(x)= \lim\int s_k d\mu(x)$ then $\int s_k d\mu(x)=0$ and $\sum \alpha_n \mu(A_n)=0$ where $s_k= \sum \alpha_n \chi(A_n)$ which show that $\mu=0$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Your proof is sloppy is that you are not specifying a value for $n$ nor using it at all; and the sequence $\{s_k\}$ plays no role either, you could have just taken a single step function. You seem to assume that $\mu$ is a positive measure; in that case it is enough to require $\int x^n\,d\mu(x)$ for a single $n$ to get $\mu=0$. I would suspect that the original question is about a complex (or at least signed) measure.

Comment: this is Exercise 3.6.4 of Conway's Functional analysis and I wrote it completely.

Comment: In that case, if you look at the way measures are used in that chapter, you'll see that $\mu$ is not assumed to be positive. It is also clear that the topics in the section have nothing to do with measure theory,  so you shouldn't treat this as a measure theory exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the dual $C[0,1]$ is isomorphic to $M([0,1])$, the space of Borel measures on $[0,1]$, to which $\mu$ belongs. So what you really need to prove is :

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $S\subset X$ is such that the span of $S$ is dense in $X$. If $f \in X^{\ast}$ is a continuous linear functional such that $f(y) = 0$ for all $y\in S$, then $f\equiv 0$

Does this help?

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much